# Find values of $a$ for which $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a}\log ( 1 + n^{-1}) $ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\log ( 1 + 1/n) / n^{a} $. What are the values of $a$ such that it converges?

I think we cannot apply series expansion of $\log$ here. How should I do it?

Comment: **Hint:** For P1, you actually can: use the comparison test, observing that $\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{n^a} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{a+1}}$ since $\ln(1+x)\operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to0} x$.

Comment: OP: Please do not modify the question after some answers are posted. Here, P2 is unrelated to the original question P1 and should be posted as another question.

Answer (score 3):

> I think we cannot apply series expansion of log here

Hmmm... Actually, that $\log(1+1/n)\sim1/n$ yields that the series is (absolutely) convergent for every $a\gt0$ and divergent for every $a\leqslant0$.

That there exists an exact value of the sum when $a\gt0$ is unlikely.

Comment: This series does not converge. Perhaps you meant $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\zeta(a+n)$$ the following converges quite a bit faster $$\log(2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n(\zeta(a+n)-1)$$

Comment: @robjohn No I did not mean that. Removed problematic part of the answer.